# Laravel 5.4 Authenticating

Tags: php, laravel

I've got questions and problems:
First here is my code:

AuthMiddleware.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (auth()->check()) {
        return $next($request);
    } else {
        if (auth()->viaRemember()) {
            return $next($request);
        }
    }


    return redirect()->route('auth.index');

}
```

AuthController.php

```
if (auth()->attempt(compact('email', 'password'), true)) {

        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
}
```

Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth.check'       => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthMiddleware::class,
 ]
```

routes.php

```
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'AuthController@index')->name('auth.index');
    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth.check'], function () {
    Route::get('dashboard', function () {
        return view('front.welcome');
    })->name('dashboard');
});
```

Here is the problem:

1. Every time I close my browser (with `expire_on_close:true` on
   session file) the page will redirect me to `/login` instead of
   `/auth`. I can't find the code why it redirect me to `/login`. Any solution?
2. I want to apply rememberMe function. But every time I close my browser it always log me out. I've tried set `expire_on_close:false`. Yes, it's working but everytime I run `auth()->viaRemember()` it always return me false. Any suggestion?

My Session using file.

Comment: Have you checked middleware? It redirects to login there I guess

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar I only apply my custom middleware `auth.check` to routes. I don't see any code redirect me to login at my middleware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Check `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` That's where the redirect to login is. Function name is `unauthenticated()`;

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    return redirect()->guest('login'); //HERE
}
```

2- When you remember, just doing `Auth::check()` or `Auth::viaRemember()` should work when the user comes back to the website.

Comment: Hi, Yes!! that solve the problem.. And why it enter exception instead of my middleware?.

Comment: My GUESS is that it's because you are using `Auth` so it always redirects there in case of exception.

Comment: What about to apply the remember me what should I set the value for expire_on_close?

Comment: Set the value of `expire_on_close` to `false`.

Comment: Sadly the remember me function never work. I close the browser, and try re-open the browser. It always log me out. Instead of take the rememberme cookie

Comment: Try to clear your configuration cache `php artisan config:cache`. Closing the browser shouldn't end the session when you have `expre_on_close` set to false.

Comment: after I run `config:cache` all my app is down. the .env file cannot be read.

Comment: Then do `php artisan config:clear` to clear your configuration cache.